# Function to return values from metabox

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta

I have created two custom metaboxes using the Meta Box plugin for my cpt called books, and I am confused how to output the values. The values need to be used in sperate places in one of my templates. I tried using `get_post_custom()` and with `get_post_meta()` but couldn't get it to work.

Here is my metabox template:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'rw_register_meta_boxes');
function rw_register_meta_boxes()
{
    $prefix       = 'rw_';
    $meta_boxes   = array();
    // Here is the code to define a meta box
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title' => 'Amazon Affiliate Link',
        'pages' => array(
            'books'
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'url',
                'id' => $prefix . 'amz',
                'type' => 'text'
            )
        )
    );
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title' => 'Subtitle',
        'pages' => array(
            'books'
        ),
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Subtitle',
                'id' => $prefix . 'subt',
                'type' => 'text'
            )
        )
    );
    foreach ($meta_boxes as $meta_box) {
        new RW_Meta_Box($meta_box);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the plugin 'Meta Box'. It should actually work fine if you try it with this line (Example with the Amazon Affiliate), just substitute `$bookID` with your ID or get_the_ID():

```
echo get_post_meta( $bookID, 'rw_amz', true );
```

Oh, and i just saw that you opened two `array` when defining your fields, the correct code should be:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'rw_register_meta_boxes' );
function rw_register_meta_boxes() {
    $prefix = 'rw_';
    $meta_boxes = array();
    // Here is the code to define a meta box
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'    => 'Amazon Affiliate Link',
        'pages'    => array( 'books' ),
        'fields' => array(
            'name' => 'url',
            'id'   => $prefix . 'amz',
            'type' => 'text',
        )
    );
    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'title'    => 'Subtitle',
        'pages'    => array( 'books' ),
        'fields' => array(
            'name' => 'Subtitle',
            'id'   => $prefix . 'subt',
            'type' => 'text',
        )
    );
    foreach ( $meta_boxes as $meta_box ) {
        new RW_Meta_Box( $meta_box );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @fischi, this worked perfectly. I edited the question to say that I am using the MEta Box plugin, can't belive I forgot to mention that!